# How can retrive current user id on Laravel 8 api controller?

Tags: php, laravel, rest, laravel-8

i searched everywhere for solution, the problem is that i need current user logged id in my api controller. in the api controller i put the middleware api.
Here is the code of ApiController.php:

```
 public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:api');
}
public function createcorso(Request $request)
{

    $corsoscii = new CorsoScii();

    $corsoscii->tipo = $request->input('tipo');
    $corsoscii->nome = $request->input('nome');
    $corsoscii->membriMax = $request->input('membriMax');
    $corsoscii->orario_inizio = $request->input('orario_inizio');
    $corsoscii->orario_fine = $request->input('orario_fine');
    $corsoscii->inizio = $request->input('inizio');
    $corsoscii->fine = $request->input('fine');

    $corsoscii->save();

    $idUtente =  $request->user('api')->id;  
    $idCorso = CorsoScii::latest()->first();
    DB::table('iscrizione')->insert(
        array('idUtente' => $idUtente, 'idCorso' => $idCorso)
    );
    return response()->json($corsoscii);
}
```

This is the api.php routes:

```
Auth::routes();

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});


//Operazioni di gestione e creazione corso scii per maestri
Route::post('/tipo', [App\Http\Controllers\ApiController::class, 'createtipo']);
Route::post('/corso', [App\Http\Controllers\ApiController::class, 'createcorso']);
Route::get('/mostracorsi', [App\Http\Controllers\ApiController::class, 'mostracorsi']);
Route::get('/mostracorso/{idCorso}', [App\Http\Controllers\ApiController::class, 'mostracorso']);
Route::put('/updatecorso/{idCorso}', [App\Http\Controllers\ApiController::class, 'updatecorso']);
Route::delete('/deletecorso/{idCorso}', [App\Http\Controllers\ApiController::class, 'deletecorso']);

//Operazioni di gestione prenotazioni ed iscrizioni per clienti impianto scii
Route::post('/iscrizione', [App\Http\Controllers\ApiController::class, 'iscrizione']);
Route::get('/vedicorso/{idCorso}', [App\Http\Controllers\ApiController::class, 'vedicorso']);
Route::delete('/deleteiscrizione/{idUtente}', [App\Http\Controllers\ApiController::class, 'deleteiscrizione']);

Auth::routes();
```

When i tried to insert data on a form it gives me this error:
[image]

User not authenthicated even if is not true. Maybe something is wrong in the middleware configuration.

Comment: Your function `createcorso` wasn't reached, because you are `Unathorized`. You have to provide correct credentials first.

Comment: In the case of an API, you have to provide the token identifying the user.

Comment: No, you'll need a method to login the user, which will generate an JWT token. Is that token that you will provide.

Comment: Ok thanks i will try

Comment: This link explain how to generate the JWT token: https://blog.pusher.com/laravel-jwt/

Comment: I tried to install tymon/jwt-auth, i followed the link you gave me, the [documentation] (https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/quick-start/) and the [github repository project] (https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth). I followed all the istructions but it gives me some problems when i created the AuthController, because auth()->attempt($credentials) is not defined and same for the other four methods. I don't understand why i checked also the jwt.php and auth.php configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the logged in user detail

you can access it as below

```
auth()->user()->id
```

But that will return some id when the user is logged in already. you can use

JWT, Passport etc for API authentication.

Comment: I tried to install Passport following the official Laravel Documentation. When i tried to run `php artisan migrate` in order to create oauth tables it gives me this error:`Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'password_resets' already exists (SQL: create table 
`password_resets` (`email` varchar(255) not null, `token` varchar(255) not null, `created_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')`. Tables already exixst. How can i install properly Passport?

Comment: drop table password_resets and then run php artisan migrate